# Is there a WordPress theme for twittstrap?

Tags: themes, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know if there is a WordPress theme that uses [twittstrap](http://www.twittstrap.com) (a derivative from Twitter Bootstrap)?

Comment: Link to [twittstrap](http://www.twittstrap.com/twittstrap)

Comment: What do you mean by "WordPress implementation"? WordPress is CMS written in PHP. Twittstrap is HTML/CSS/JS framework, so of course you can use it with WordPress...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen anything out there for that specific flavor of Bootstrap.

If you want a Custom Bootstrap theme on Wordpress, and you don't want to code it from scratch, I would suggest downloading the [WP-Bootstrap](http://320press.com/wpbs/) theme and a Bootstrap theme from a site like [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/). You'll have to replace some css files, but that should get you pretty far.

Hope that helps.